Is there a way to pass an argument to an access macro or submacro from a button
I want to write submacros that open reports from forms.
My forms would have buttons that say things like "Print Report", "Show Print View", etc.
I want to call the same submacros from different forms, since the only difference is the name of the report.
The buttons would call the macro with the name of the report.
Is there a way to pass the name of the report from the button to the macro?
I'm pretty sure it is possible in VBA, but I want to know if it will work as a macro
TIA

Explore TempVars. Why not use VBA?

I could use VBA, but I wanted to become more familiar with macros.  How would the TempVar get the value passed to it from the button?

Code for button click event would set TempVar variable. I only use VBA and have never used TempVars in my apps. I am not sure where the TempVar variable would be created so that it could then be referenced by other elements.

I did some testing. Macro action SetTempVar is used to create and set a TempVars variable. If it was already created and set by another procedure, it will simply be replaced. However, I am not sure TempVars will actually be useful. Might as well just have the button call the report directly.
